# vala interface with get property - compilation error

Tags: c#, vala

I am relatively new to [Vala](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/Tutorial#Interfaces) and I'm trying to port some C# code into vala by hand and I have started out with a trivial example to test it out.

C# coders will recognize the snippet below as being 1-1 mapping to C#.

Here is the test vala file Universe.vala:

```
namespace Universe
{
    public interface Planet
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

I get the compilation error:

> Universe.vala: error: property getter must have a body

It would appear that Vala does not support get(set)ter properties in interfaces - or am I missing something?. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vala interfaces can still contain non-abstract properties and methods (but no variables). This means if you want to define an abstract property or method, you still need to use the `abstract` keyword, just like you would in an abstract class.

Since you did not use the `abstract` keyword here, the compiler thinks you're trying to define a non-abstract property. However non-abstract properties in interfaces need an explicit body (because the default implementation would need to use variables, which are not allowed). So that's why the error message is complaining about the missing body.

Just add the `abstract` keyword and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed that error - however, I get a compile error on the first line of the file now: `Universe.vala:1.1-1.1: error: syntax error, unexpected character namespace Universe`

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli If I add `abstract` to the code you posted, it compiles fine for me. The compiler should be drawing a little arrow pointing at the character it's complaining about. Where does it point?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The arrow is pointing to the first character of the keyword 'namespace' (i.e. the first character of the first line). Incidentally, I am running vala v 0.8.0 on Ubuntu 10.0.4 with gcc v 4.4.3

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Okay, I should have gotten that from the line and column number... Anyway no idea why it complains about the namespace keyword (or more importantly why it didn't before you added the abstract keyword). Is there any chance that some non-printable character somehow made its way into the file?

Comment: I think you're right, I used vim to edit the file. I think I will be able to fix that myself. I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your answer + help.